# Достать значение из тэга. Парсинг html

Tags: android, html, jsoup, парсер

Использую библиотеку JSOUP. Вот кусок HTML, который я парсю:

```
<div class="mp_text">       
    <div id="news-id-XXX" style="display:inline;">Текст статьи</div>    
</div>
```

При помощи следующего куска кода, я достаю значение `Текст статьи`:

```
Elements elements = doc.select(".mp_text");
for (Element el : elements) {
    list.add(el.text());
}
```

Но мне нужно достать значение `news-id-XXX`, текст самой статьи меня не интересует. Перепробовал многие комбинации кода - не получается. Пожалуйста, помогите :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `doc.select(".mp_text")` вы получаете родительский div, внутри которого находятся интересующие вас статьи. Вам нужно либо обратиться к дочерним элементам `el`, либо при выборе элементов сразу взять дочерние. Ниже реализация 2го варианта:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String html =
        "<html>" +
        "<body>" +
        "   <div class=\"mp_text\">" +
        "       <div id=\"news-id-XXX\" style=\"display:inline;\">Текст статьи</div>" +
        "   </div>" +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements elements = doc.select(".mp_text div");
for (Element el : elements) {
    list.add(el.id());
}
System.out.println(list); //[news-id-XXX]
```

Comment: Николай, спасибо! Это прям то, что было нужно :)

Comment: Николай, прошу вас о помощи с решением следующего вопроса: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721042/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-c-jsoup-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-element]